# Cursor can't execute through a prepare statement in mysql stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql

my code is:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`windows7test-pc` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`()
BEGIN
declare str varchar(4000);
set str='declare cur cursor for select *from student';
set @st=str;
prepare stmt from @st;
execute stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
open cur;//error 1324:undefined cursor...... why?
END
```

why  cursur is not declare here?please notify me my problem

Comment: Probably because dynamic SQL is in another context and after it ends all objects are not in scope.

Comment: This question is an example of an **XY Problem**. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378 OP has asked several similar question about conditionally/dynamically declaring a cursor in MySQL stored procedure. What OP hasn't revealed is *why* he would need to do this. OP has not identified the *actual problem* he is trying to solve. (The question OP asked "why can't a cursor be declared in a prepared statement" is answered in the MySQL Reference Manual.)

Comment: OP says "notify me my problem".  The *problem* with the code in this question (and the code in similar questions asked by OP) is that it's *not possible* to dynamically declare a cursor. The MySQL Reference Manual documents the syntax used to declare a cursor, as well as limitations on where that syntax can appear.

Answer (score 1):

excerpt:

> ... a cursor cannot be used for a dynamic statement that is prepared and executed with PREPARE and EXECUTE. The statement for a cursor is checked at cursor creation time, so the statement cannot be dynamic.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Note that the documentation includes a section **SQL Syntax Allowed in Prepared Statements**, and that neither '`DECLARE`' nor '`CURSOR`' appear in the list of allowed syntax.

Comment: :-sir is there any another way to do this code?i want to declare cursor in IF.. ELSE block and open that cursor in another IF..ELSE block.please.....

Comment: A cursor declaration cannot be dynamic (in a MySQL stored procedure.) I do not understand what problem OP is trying to solve. And I don't see why a cursor would be needed at all. If there's some reason the procedure needs a cursor, then just DECLARE the &@%# CURSOR. The OPEN of the cursor can be a conditional IF ,,, THEN block.

Comment: @Arunnagar declaring a cursor in one `IF` block and opening it a different `IF` block **makes no sense**.  If you aren't going to open it, don't declare it.  Placing both statements in an inner (nested) `BEGIN`/`END` block will solve the problem you seem to be trying to solve with this apparent [XY question](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: We had this discussion in another question by OP (deleted by now I guess), it's the 4th or 5th question about this topic now. Unfortunately OP is kind of stuborn with this.